# Netbeans: linking static library to the project

Tags: c++, netbeans, static-libraries

How can I properly link the static library into the Netbeans project?

I am trying to build my app on the FreeBSD - I got the .a and the .h files of my library (the library is the devil graphic library btw.)

I have added the include directory for the library in the:

`File => Project Properties => Build => C++ Compiler => General => Include Directories`

then, under the `File => Project Properties => Build => Linkers => Libraries` added my library as a file: `../../../source/devil/libIL.a`

However, when I am compiling it I get the following error:

`No rule to make target ../../../source/devil/libIL.a`

(I have also tried to add the `-static` flag at the begging of the library path in the linkers libraries.

Comment: Did you try to add a extra lib `dir` (not only the lib itself) to find libraries @ `Properties->Build->Linker`? Other shot, try to add `-lIL` at Linker `addional options` field.

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding the library directory path as well. Regarding the `-lIL` option at the Linker's additional options I get the following error then: `/usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find -lIL`.

Comment: Sorry, I should mean both options, so `-lLD` should look exact for `libIL.a` following the lib directories.

Comment: @wesley.mesquita You mean adding the library path + the library file to the linker? I have already tried that, if I will include the library file (libIL.a) in the linker I get `No rule to make target` otherwise I get `/usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find -lIL`

Comment: I meant add the PATH to find the lib + option `-lIL`.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, params indirectly sent to the loader must be preceded with `-Wl,`, as stated in the manual of ld (`man ld`):

> Note---if the linker is being invoked indirectly, via a compiler driver (e.g. gcc) then all the linker command line options should be prefixed by -Wl, (or whatever is appropriate for the particular compiler driver) like this: `gcc -Wl,--start-group foo.o bar.o -Wl,--end-group`

On Netbeans use the "Add Option..." button in the libraries menu (Project Properties > Linker > Libraries) to do so:

[image: Screenshot of Netbeans libraries menu]

In the previous image, I've used `-Wl,-static` to link all of the previous libraries statically.

Cheers,